# Eclipse with JDK in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, java

A short question: My eclipse project is set to use the "sun-java-6-jdk"-supplied JDK library, but I cannot Ctrl-click to view source (no source attached), as I can do out-of-the-box on Windows. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the **openjdk-6-source** package and to attach the sources (located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/src.zip`) to the JDK under Eclipse.

Personally, I prefer to use **sun-java6-jdk** - the source package being **sun-java6-source** - that you can get from the Canonical Partner Repository:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
```

Then, attach the sources located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/src.zip`

Comment: How inconvenient. It works, but it's not really user friendly. Windows > Linux, for once :P

Comment: In Ubuntu, executing this may just be enough (it was, for me): `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-source`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably that's because it hasn't got source with the JAR so it's not finding it automatically. Your best bet is to consult the ubuntu package manager and see if there's a  src, or if it's elsewhere on your system (/use/src or /use/local are places to start looking).

Once you've got it, you can right-click on the JAR in the project and point to the location of the Java source in the "source" property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to the settings for your installed JRE, edit it, and set the source attachments manually.

Here's a link to Eclipse's help: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-installed_jres.htm